# Dynamic file name with AngularJS shows JSHint error

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

My DOM with AngularJS has the following element...

```
<img class="optional" src="assets/img/{{ctrl.optional}}.png" ng-click="ctrl.clickOptional()">
```

The image is generated dynamically when the page is loaded. When I click on this image, the function `clickOptional()` in my controller run perfectly changing the image.

The issue is, when the browser load my page, the console show the following error:

```
http://localhost:8787/public/assets/img/%7B%7Bbctrl.optional%7D%7D.png Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

I know this occur because the DOM structure is checked before than AngularJS be loaded.

Are there some workaround to fix it? What's the best way to do it?

Comment: try using ng-src instead of src

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is because browser can "see" raw url, which has "%7B%7Bbctrl.optional%7D%7D" part. You can fix this by putting ng-src instead of src, like

```
<img ng-src="assets/img/{{ctrl.optional}}.png">
```

More here https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc